# If the following configuration duplicate in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

when specifying compiler version, I use the following two

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

and

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

I am wondering if those two are duplicated?

Comment: Yes. The first one is enough. If you like and should define the version of the plugin via pluginManagement.

Comment: BTW: You should use a more recent version of the [maven-compiler-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/)...

Comment: could you add this as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the properties variant or the explicit variant. I would suggest to make it that way.

```
<project..>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artfiactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ..
</project>
```

I usually encourage users to have a corporate pom which contains the definition of the plugin versions (in our case the `pluginManagement`part including other plugins as well) and in your own pom you could use the properties to define the `source/target` which to build for this would look like this:

```
<project..>

  <parent>
     <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
     <artfiactId>corporate-pom</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.2</version>
  </parent>      

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  </build>
  ..
</project>
```

The above scenarios are not 100% correct cause with the above you could use JDK 8 parts in your code (if you are compiling with JDK 8) which would fail if you need to run it on a JRE 7. To handle this correctly have to use [maven-toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) and [animalsniffer-maven-plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/)

If you are using JDK 9+ you should enhance your configuration like this:

```
<project..>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.release>9</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artfiactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ..
</project>
```